# Overwriting file warning

Tags: filecontents

Is it possible to suppress the warning generated by:

```
\begin{filecontents*}
```

Every time it outputs the warning: Overwriting file 'xxxx.xxx'.
Maybe to delete it before it creates a new one or something like that?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `silence` package to mute the warning:

```
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Overwriting file}
```